# Code coverage with Xcode 4.2 - Missing files

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage

I followed [Claus's post](http://www.infinite-loop.dk/blog/2011/12/code-coverage-with-xcode-4-2/) to set up code coverage on Xcode 4.2 with LLVM 3.0. I'm able to see test coverage files, but they're only for my unit test classes, not my actual project classes. I've tried setting **Generate Test Coverage Files** and **Instrument Program Flow** to **Yes** on my main target, but that didn't help, as it failed with the following error:

fopen$UNIX2003 called from function llvm_gcda_start_file

To clarify, I don't think that's even the right approach - I just tried it to see if it would generate code coverage on my project classes.

At this point, I'd be happy to try anything that gets code coverage working on my app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are expecting linker problem, `profile_rt` library uses `fopen$UNIX2003` and `fwrite$UNIX2003` functions instead of `fopen` and `fwrite`.

All you need is to add the following `.c` file to your project:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fopen$UNIX2003( const char *filename, const char *mode )
{
    return fopen(filename, mode);
}

size_t fwrite$UNIX2003( const void *a, size_t b, size_t c, FILE *d )
{
    return fwrite(a, b, c, d);
}
```

This code just remaps the missing functions to standard ones.

**Note on `$UNIX2003` suffix:**

I've found an [Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Darwin/SymbolVariantsRelNotes/_index.html) saying:

> The UNIX™ conformance variants use the $UNIX2003 suffix.
>
> Important: The work for UNIX™ conformance started in Mac OS 10.4, but was not completed until 10.5. Thus, in the 10.4 versions of libSystem.dylib, many of the conforming variant symbols (with the $UNIX2003 suffix) exist. The list is not complete, and the conforming behavior of the variant symbols may not be complete, so they should be avoided.
>
> Because the 64-bit environment has no legacy to maintain, it was created to be UNIX™ conforming from the start, without the use of the $UNIX2003 suffix. So, for example, _fputs$UNIX2003 in 32-bit and _fputs in 64-bit will have the same conforming behavior.

So I expect `libprofile_rt` to be linked against 10.4 SDK.

Comment: Adding this .c file to my project in XCode 4.3.2 and turning on coverage and instrumentation for my main target (debug only) worked! This is the first time I've had fully functional code coverage working for iOS development. I even got it integrated with Jenkins using gcovr and the Coburtura plugin.

Comment: That works for me 99% of the time, but I still randomly get a crash.  Any thoughts?  Our test framework will restart the app 100's of times.  On overnight runs and it always occurs, but very intermittently

Comment: @BrianKing You should probably file a separate question with details on your crash.

Comment: It's an old thread. But that answer just saved my day! Was having problems with compiling LevelDB library for iOS8

Answer (score 2):

I use CoverStory http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/ a GUI for `.gcda` and `.gcno` files.

The documentation explains the settings needed to generate these files http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/UsingCoverstory.

Comment: CoverStory worked great for me. Enabling Code coverage on XCode 4.5 is really easy with no need to add additional libs.