# Xcode Code Coverage and fopen$UNIX2003

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, code-coverage

I am facing what seems to be a pretty wide spread issue : when I activate code coverage in Xcode (4.2.1) with Lion it shows the following error :

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
fopen$UNIX2003 called from function llvm_gcda_start_file
```

I followed the workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732393/code-coverage-with-xcode-4-2-missing-files) and added a file to my test target with a mapping for the fopen function but it won't work for me. With the new C file, I get a lot of Parse and Semantic issues, as if it was completly messing the compilator up.

Is there a specific config/compiler option I am missing ? How exactly should I add the new file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was fixed when I renamed the .c file in a .m file... I don't know if it could be an issue linked to ARC for instance.