# Using library in iOS simulator: Linking with Unix Conformance Layer

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker, ios-simulator

I am developing a framework for other iOS developers and I am using boost as a dependency. I am creating a boost.framework which contains the libraries (fat library) for arm6, arm7, arm7s, arm64, i386 and x86_64. Compilation and linking seems to work fine, but using my library and the boost.framework in XCode 5.0.2 in a simulator results in the following error

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
pthread_cond_init$UNIX2003 called from function _ZN5boost18condition_variableC2Ev
```

However, deploying the App on a device does not yield any problems at all.

After looking around I found a [StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732393/code-coverage-with-xcode-4-2-missing-files/8733416#8733416) explaining that his `$UNIX2003` function names are part of the OSX library. Based on that I checked the linking of the library and only the i386 parts of the library are linked against the `$UNIX2003` parts (which is in accordance to [Apple's own description](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Darwin/SymbolVariantsRelNotes/index.html)). The arm* architectures are using the unsuffixed versions.

My question is, what can I do to have it running on the simulator? Do I need to recompile boost with specific flags? Is there an option to tell the simulator to shut up? Or is there at least I way to tell the simulator to use the actual device libraries not the i386 ones?

There is the possibility of writing these `$UNIX2003` functions myself which then delegate to the real ones. But since there are quite a few function calls I would rather not do that, especially since the developers using my framework would need to do the same I guess (which I would like to avoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coming across [a discussion on an unrelated mailing list](http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2011q1/026627.html), I found the original culprit: The boost library was built against the Mac OS X version of (I guess libc++), not against the iPhone simulator version of it. Fixing this generated the framework in the proper formats as well as containing only links to the proper versions of the system calls.

Comment: sorry, the link is broken. I have similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609034/stat-unavailable-in-ios-simulator), how can i fix it?