# stat() unavailable in ios simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, llvm, stat

I've compiled and linked ios app that uses lib (libclang) that uses stat() with no errors. But i'm having runtime error:

> 2014-07-07 16:55:14.138 LibClangUsage7Demo[74938:60b] started Detected
>   an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on
>   the iPhone: stat$INODE64 called from function
>   _ZN4llvm3sys2fs6statusERKNS_5TwineERNS1_11file_statusE in image LibClangUsage7Demo.

LLVM code which raises error is (/Unix/Path.inc):

```
error_code status(const Twine &Path, file_status &Result) {
  SmallString<128> PathStorage;
  StringRef P = Path.toNullTerminatedStringRef(PathStorage);

  struct stat Status;
  int StatRet = ::stat(P.begin(), &Status); // failure here
  return fillStatus(StatRet, Status, Result);
}
```

How was i able to link the app without having stat() in symbols? How can i fix/walk-around it?

PS. I can see `stat` is supported by iOS (Simulator?):
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/stat.2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [was said](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1000186#1000186) `stat` is not supported on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you built libclang for OSX and linked it into an iOS executable.  You need to build libclang for the correct platform.

stat certainly is supported on iOS.