# How to fix LLVM/Clang using missing stat() function on iOS?

Tags: ios, clang, llvm

LLVM/Clang uses `stat()` function to get file info (/Unix/Path.inc):

```
error_code status(const Twine &Path, file_status &Result) {
  SmallString<128> PathStorage;
  StringRef P = Path.toNullTerminatedStringRef(PathStorage);

  struct stat Status;
  int StatRet = ::stat(P.begin(), &Status); // failure here
  return fillStatus(StatRet, Status, Result);
}
```

but it fails to run on iOS simulator with error:

> 2014-07-07 16:55:14.138 LibClangUsage7Demo[74938:60b] started Detected
>   an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on
>   the iPhone: stat$INODE64 called from function
>   _ZN4llvm3sys2fs6statusERKNS_5TwineERNS1_11file_statusE in image LibClangUsage7Demo.

For some reason `stat()` [is said to be missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609034/stat-unavailable-in-ios-simulator) on iOS simulator though some people say they are able to use it in regular iOS apps.

How can i fix/workaround it (rewrite with another file API, mock stat() with NS.. or smth)?

Comment: Why don't you mention what you are trying to accomplish?  Then people might be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: I'm trying to use LLVM/Clang in iOS app, so i've cross-compiled LLVM/Clang (having lib*.a), imported LLVM/Clang headers in XCode project and trying to use libclang c api functions. I'm able to build iOS app with LLVM/Clang static libs but it fails in runtime

Comment: I don't want to extend iOS kernel and the aim is just to use highlighting provided by LLVM/Clang on iOS. I ask you not to write such rude and not constructive comments any more. If you are not experienced enough just leave the question

Comment: Well, in fairness, you appear pretty stubborn about this issue.  If it's not implemented in iOS then it is not implemented.  There is nothing that can be done.  That's why I suggest stating what you want to do (don't say "I want to use this function" because that's not valid and leads us around in circles).  You should edit this question to include a development goal, otherwise I'm going to mark it as a duplicate of your last question.

Comment: Another file API can be available (except NS..) so i'm sure it just a question of finding a person who knows how to solve it. Someone was able to do it - port LLVM/Clang to ios: http://leoth3o.wordpress.com/2013/09/. I've removed that question so it's not duplicate now.